# MySQLのport番号をシェルスクリプトの関数内で指定する方法

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, bash

port forwardingを使って、リモートでMySQLにアクセスする方法について質問させていただきます。

以下に簡単なdemo script（demo.sh）を作成しました。

```sh
echo $1;
echo $2;
echo "$HOME/local/bin/mysql -u user -D WB -h$1 --port=$2"　　（<-ここのコマンドは正常に動きます。）

query() {
    $HOME/local/bin/mysql -u user -D WB -h$1 --port=$2
}

query "begin;\
         #some command for MySQL
      commit;"
```

OSはubuntu16.04を使って、portの番号を13306に設定しております。

```
bash demo.sh xxxx 13306
(xxxは実際のIP addressです。)
```

とタイプしますと、
mysql: [ERROR] /home/user/local/bin/mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified
というエラーが出てきます。
自分の理解では、portの番号が指定されていないことがエラーの原因だと思います。

しかし、3番目のechoの結果を、直接terminalにコピペしますと、正常にMySQLにアクセスできます。このことより、コマンド自体は問題ないと考えております。

質問ですが、bash scriptではEmpty value for 'port' specifiedとなってしまっている部分を、何とかport番号を指定する方法はありますでしょうか？

ーPオプションも試してみましたが、問題は解決しませんでした。

もし何方かご存知でしたら、ご教授をお願いします。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3行目のechoコマンドを query() の中に移動してみれば原因がわかると思います。
関数内の $1 $2 等は、関数外の値を引き継ぎません。関数呼び出し時に与えられた引数になります。

今回のスクリプトの場合は $1 は "begin;～" の文字列になり、$2 は空になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。不勉強のため「関数内の $1 $2 等は、関数外の値を引き継ぎません。」を知りませんでした。お恥ずかしい限りです。これでようやく原因がわかりました。 $1 $2 等が引き数を取っていると完全に思い込んでおりましたので、tmtms様からの助言は大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。